# Find Group Specific Maximum Value with Condition in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
df1 <- structure(list(year = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L),
       county = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), 
       party = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1","P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1"),
       list_position = c("2", "3", "1", "3", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1", "3", "2", "1"),
       elected = c("1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

df1
   year county party list_position elected
1  2013      A    P1             2       1
2  2013      A    P1             3       0
3  2013      A    P1             1       1
4  2013      B    P1             3       0
5  2013      B    P1             2       0
6  2013      B    P1             1       1
7  2017      A    P1             2       1
8  2017      A    P1             3       0
9  2017      A    P1             1       1
10 2017      B    P1             3       0
11 2017      B    P1             2       1
12 2017      B    P1             1       1
```

where `list_position` contains information which position on an electoral list a candidate from a political `party` (the data contains several parties, not just `P1`) takes in a given `year` and `county`. Now, I want a new variable that contains information on the maximum value of `list_position` at which a candidate has been elected. This would look as follows:

```
   year county party list_position elected max_list_position
1  2013      A    P1             2       1                 2
2  2013      A    P1             3       0                 2
3  2013      A    P1             1       1                 2
4  2013      B    P1             3       0                 1
5  2013      B    P1             2       0                 1
6  2013      B    P1             1       1                 1
7  2017      A    P1             2       1                 2
8  2017      A    P1             3       0                 2
9  2017      A    P1             1       1                 2
10 2017      B    P1             3       0                 3
11 2017      B    P1             2       1                 3
12 2017      B    P1             1       1                 3
```

I tried

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(year, county, party) %>%
  mutate(max_list_position= max(list_position [elected == 1])) %>%
  ungroup()
```

but for some reason R gives me `-Inf` values for some of the observations for `max_list_position`

Comment: Do the year-county-party combinations with `-Inf` have at least one row with `elected==1`?

Comment: no... is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% type.convert(as.is = T) %>% group_by(year, county) %>% 
mutate(max_list_position = max(list_position[elected==1])[1])
# A tibble: 12 x 6
# Groups:   year, county [4]
    year county party list_position elected max_list_position
   <int> <chr>  <chr>         <int>   <int>             <int>
 1  2013 A      P1                2       1                 2
 2  2013 A      P1                3       0                 2
 3  2013 A      P1                1       1                 2
 4  2013 B      P1                3       0                 1
 5  2013 B      P1                2       0                 1
 6  2013 B      P1                1       1                 1
 7  2017 A      P1                2       1                 2
 8  2017 A      P1                3       0                 2
 9  2017 A      P1                1       1                 2
10  2017 B      P1                3       0                 2
11  2017 B      P1                2       1                 2
12  2017 B      P1                1       1                 2
>
```

Comment: no, unfortunately the're still observations with -Inf

Comment: @nick_dataFE, if you have no candidates that were elected, what do you want the result in new column to be? Also, can you include such cases in your same data?

Answer (score 0):

I did not notice that I indeed have observations for which no candidate in counties were elected. That caused the problem